# The Best way to keep SSL certificate in Mobile application

Tags: ios, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I want to implement mobile application with **SSL Certificate**. *I know that we can keep the SSL certificate inside the Application*. 
I need clarification in the following questions.

- If SSL Certificate inside the mobile application. How can **update certificate in Feature**?
- Is any way to **keep certificate keep in server**. And **call mobile application web service**?
- Is Keep inside the application how can **I trust is secure**. (In cause of reverse Engineering)

Answer (score 0):

u have to implement ssl certificate in server and u can added in ur info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>testdomain.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.2</string>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.2</string>
        <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

this are the options u can add in ur code for security

Comment: Hi @vaibby Thanks!. If you possible can you explain how its work in application.

Comment: What about the security of the certificate. How can ensure that the certificate couldn't access others.